# Openshift - Unable to invoke request Error

Tags: java, rest, security, jax-rs, openshift

I've written a REST service that sends JSON format of my objects, I tested the client in my local machine with wildfly 8.2.1 and it works perfect. But when I invoke/test the same URL with a simple REST Java client from openshift I get the following error:

> 1.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request 
>   2.at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
>   3.at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
>   4.at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:450)
>   5.at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.get(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:171)
>   6.at br.com.lidertec.miletwstest.mb.ClientesMB.getClientes(ClientesMB.java:33)
>   7.at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

Comment: 1.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request 2.at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)

Comment: 34.Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Comment: add full stacktrace to the question

Comment: You can edit the question to add the error details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed some English issues and marked up your error message.  This is done using >

It would help others to help you if you provided more information such as stack trace, or actual code.